# How to create a link to a location in the body of an email in Outlook

Tags: outlook, hyperlink, outlook-2007

Is there a way to create a hyperlink in an email that refers to another location within that same email?

All intended recipients are all Outlook users, so if there is a solution for only that case, even that will be great!

Answer (score 14):

When you create new e-mail in Outlook (I have 2007):

1. Go to 'Insert' tab in main menu
2. Find 'Hyperlink' button.
3. In the opened form you'll be able to chose somethings like "another place in this document"
4. This will work if you want to link to headers. If you want to link to an arbitrary location, you will need to add a bookmark to that location first (button near the hyperlink button). You will then be able to create a hyperlink to this bookmark.

I have Russian localization so I'm not sure if I translated everything correct.

Answer (score 3):

**In a new email or when editing existing email:**

1. First stand on the line/location and mark/highlight the text part you want to link **to**
2. Click on Insert tab
3. From the top banner click on **Bookmark**
   A bookmark dialog will popup, which looks like this (i've already picked a name for my bookmark):

[image]

4. Type a name to your bookmark (should not start with a number or special characters)- then click on the Add button.
5. Now go to the location you want to link **from** and select the desired text.
6. Right click on the selected text -> click on Link (or hyperlink in older outlook versions)
7. In the Insert Hyperlink dialog pick "Place in This Document" - there you will see your bookmarks, select the relevant bookmark you've created and click OK - DONE!

Answer (score -1):

If you build the email in html, you will need to use  as the anchor.
You then refer to the anchor with some text here